VHDL (or Verilog equivalent) - Explanation of Syntax Being Used for this LFSR polynomial?
I have this 16-bit LFSR VHDL logic I'm working to understand and hopefully also port over from VHDL to Verilog. As I understand this LFSR there is a 2 or 4-bit polynomial tap in-use to generate the Feedback effect for the shift register:
lsfr : process (clk_i, resn_i, clk_en_i) is
begin
    if resn_i='0' then
        -- reset value / lfsr seed vector 
        lsfr_s <= "1110011110111111";
    elsif rising_edge(clk_i) and clk_en_i = '1' then
        -- generator polynomial
        -- This is the correct polynomial out of 65536 possibilities.
        if en_i='1' and lsfr_en_s='1' then
            lsfr_s <= "0"&lsfr_s(15 downto 1) xor lsfr_s(0)&"00"&lsfr_s(0)&"0"&lsfr_s(0)&"0000"&lsfr_s(0)&"00000";
        end if;
    end if;
end process lsfr;

But while I have background experience in VHDL and a little in Verilog, I haven't seen this particular Syntax strategy used for implementing the XOR/feedback AND-ing logic between the polynomial taps/output of the shift register, and the input vector to the next overall state of the LFSR vector overall. Shouldn't AND-ing any of these LFSR register values with "0" or "00", etc result in an always-0 output condition? Why are we evaluating against both "0" and "00", "0000, "00000', etc? Are these required Syntax quirks for evaluation of different portions of the register vector?

In VHDL & is used to concatenate a bit vector, rather than being a bit-wise AND. See Concatenating bits in VHDL for some examples.
This means the following expressions each create a 16-bit long vector:

"0"&lsfr_s(15 downto 1)
lsfr_s(0)&"00"&lsfr_s(0)&"0"&lsfr_s(0)&"0000"&lsfr_s(0)&"00000"

And the two 16-bits vectors are then bit-wise XORed together.
